# What kind of screw is it this with two different intertwining threads?

Tags: screws

I have a screw that is 1 1/2" long, and it has two different threads around it.  It's a button head, made for a Phillips-head screwdriver.

What do you call this kind of screw and its threading so I can search to find more of this kind of screw?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting  question; let's see if you get a good answer.

Comment: Is it double helical, or simply machined so that every other rotation is smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That type of threading is called `hi-lo`, or sometimes `high-low`.

From [MutualScrew.com](https://www.mutualscrew.com/department/high-low-screws-13478.cfm):

> High-low screws -- or hi lo screws, as they are often called -- have double-lead threads (where two grooves have been cut around the shaft). This kind of screw includes a high thread and a low thread. The unique qualities of hi-lo thread specifications help minimize the amount of material displaced as the screw is driven into the material, while also serving to create a stronger grip than would otherwise be possible.